# How or why does one gain 2 rep points for posting an answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Earlier this evening, I posted an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444620/5001) to the query [Coloring in Table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444616/5001).

Since I was already at the daily limit for rep points prior to posting this answer, the first 3 upvotes didn't increase my rep total. Nothing unexpected so far. But then something novel and quite unexpected happened: The *fourth* upvote yielded two [2!] more rep points:

[image]

As far as I can tell, this is the very first time that I've received 2 points for an upvoted answer, instead of the customary 10 points. (Of course, one doesn't get 10 points after the daily rep point limit is reached.)

Question: Is my receiving these 2 rep points due to (a) some new site-wide policy regarding rep points, (b) some site-specific software glitch, or (c) some other reason?

Two additional pieces of information: (a) No downvotes, and hence no un-downvotes, today -- or, for that matter, in at least a month. (b) The answer that generated 2 rep points upon the fourth upvote received no rep points upon a subsequent firth upvote.

Comment: When I look at your reputation tab I see +245 for yesterday https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc5JB.png. What does https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation have to say?

Comment: @moewe - Thanks. I checked a short while ago, and at the moment my rep total for yesterday is indeed `+245` -- down 2 points from the `+247` tally shown in the screenshot. I have received no notification either as to why I received +2 for my answer to "Coloring in Table of contents" or as to why the 2 points were reversed subsequently. For now, I'm inclined to think that the answer to my question is simply "(b) some site-specific software glitch".

Comment: You didn't get downvoted, but did you downvote 2 answers on that day? (I can only guess since rep penalty from downvote is not shown publicly)

Comment: @AndrewT. - No, no downvotes yesterday. According to the site stats, the most recent time I cast a downvote -- of any kind -- on TeX.SE was on June 10... Aside: I very rarely cast downvotes. If I believe there's something wrong with an answer, I much prefer to leave a note pointing out the deficiency, and I maybe even try to suggest how one might improve the answer. The only time I downvote, then, is when the posting is irredeemably poor, e.g., if it doesn't make a good-faith effort to address the question or is badly misleading -- or both.

Comment: It has happened also to me, but I believe it's just a wrong report due to miscalculations.

Answer (score 5):

This morning, about 10 hours after I posted my query, I re-checked my rep count for yesterday. At present, this rep count is back to `+245`, i.e., down 2 points from the `+247` tally shown in the screenshot posted in my query.

I have received no explanation for why I received 2 rep points for the fourth upvote of my answer to "Coloring in Table of contents". And, I've received no explanation for why the 2 points were taken off subsequently.

I'm inclined to think that the correct answer to my question,

> Is my receiving these 2 rep points due to (a) some new site-wide policy regarding rep points, (b) some site-specific software glitch, or (c) some other reason?

is simply

> (b) some site-specific software glitch

Comment: Just to report a potentially related issue. It seems that at the moment reputation changes are not reported, i.e. the green buttons do not pop up (but the score still increases and if one clicks on the reputation button on the profile one still sees the changes. Do you have the same experience?

Comment: @marmot There seems to be some problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313701/reputation-on-superuser-not-appearing-in-rep-notification-queue-yet-it-is-giv